# Preventing a user from changing a PR and merging to master in Github

Tags: security, github

I would appreciate any help to find a way to make it impossible for any single person to make changes to the master branch of a Github repository without having that change reviewed by another person. Using the usual branch protection rules, I have been unable to see how I can prevent the following scenario:

1. Person A makes a legitimate PR.
2. Person B inserts a malicious change to the PR. Then reviews the PR with their own malicious change, and subsequently merges to master.

I have considered raising the number of required reviews from 1->2, but I would prefer another solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.